# unquote a param upon passing to function using eval(substitute())

Tags: data.table, rlang

Suppose I have a simple function that uses `eval(substitue)` with an object of class `data.table`:

```
f <- function(df,col) eval(substitute(df[,mean(col)]))
```

If I then have a simple `data.table` (`d`), with columns `b1` and `b2`, I can call this function `f()`, as follows:

```
d <- data.table(b1 = c(1,2,3), b2 = c(4,5,6))

f(d,b1)
[1] 2

f(d,b2)
[1] 5
```

However, occasionally, the target column is stored as follows

```
n <- 1
target <- paste0("b", n)
```

Obviously, I cannot do `f(d,target)`. I realize that I can do `f(d,eval(parse(text = target)))`. Is there a better option to pass `target` to the function `f()`, without changing the current structure/signature of `f()`?

Comment: Add another argument to your function rather than mixing input data types: character vs symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `tryCatch` and use one of two methods:

```r
f <- function(df,col) {
  if (tryCatch(is.character(col), error = function(e) FALSE)) {
    col <- as.name(col)
  }
  eval(substitute(df[,mean(col)]))
}
f(d, b1)
# [1] 2
f(d, "b1")
# [1] 2
f(d, b2)
# [1] 5
f(d, "b2")
# [1] 5
```

Internally, `is.character(col)` either returns `TRUE` (as in `target`) or fails with `Error: object 'b1' not found`, which is when the `tryCatch` kicks in.

Comment: thanks for input, v helpful. Problem is that `f()` is much  more complicated than I've shown (but still wrapped in `eval(substitute())`).  Your solution works, but requires the full logic of `f()` to be repeated in both conditions of the if else..

Comment: Gotcha ... see my edit, better I think. @langtang

Comment: this method gets sketchy if `length(col) > 1`; for instance `f(d, c(b1,b2))` works as intended (3.5) but `f(d, c("b1","b2"))` does not.